# UUID ios for different apps

Tags: ios, objective-c, uuid

I need use id of device. But I have some problem with it. Mainly, id should be the same for different apps from different vendors. I can't use keychain because applications from different vendors and uses different provision profiles. But my server should identify this device for all these applications. Because I want see, that one device has 2 applications(with my lib), for example, and other device has one application. Something like statistics

Comment: Take a look at OpenUDID in this article, maybe it can help you: http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/04/unique-identifiers/

Comment: @tyt_g207 that will not work since OpenUDID just use the KeyChain to make the ID presisant. Thus it still will not work with app from different vendors.

Comment: it is said that OpenUDID use UIPasteBoard to persister value across application (System-wide pasteboard maybe?) (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPasteboard_Class/Reference.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible because Apple sees this a breach of privacy.

Answer (score 1):

**If you do not post application to Apple Store** (B2B mode), you can get the serial number of a device as UUID via the private Framework IOKit.

For a Category for this that encapsulates the low-level C see: https://gist.github.com/0xced/566994

Comment: Please read my answer carefully, this is not for Apple Store, it's for B2B mode (Inhouse distribution).